# How to format linear equation solve

Tags: equation-solving, formatting

I need to solve the system of linear equations $S_i = \sum_ {r = 
      1}^\lambda x_ {r, i} E_r$,
where $S_i$ is a $\lambda$ - dimensional vector, $i$ runs from 1 to $n$, $r$ runs from 1 to $\lambda$, and $x$ is a $\lambda\times n$ matrix.

I have no idea how to typeset that in Mathematica when I don' t know the values of $n$ and $\lambda$. The $S_i$ come from datasets of different sizes, and I build the $E_r$ from said datasets.

Thank you very much in advance.

Edit - Maybe this will help explain beter:
I want to avoid having to type

```
Solve[S[[i,1]]==x[[1,i]]E[[1,1]] + x[[2,i]]E[[1,2]] + ...
   && S[[i,2]]== ...
   && ...
   ];
```

for $\lambda$ rows, each one with $\lambda$ elements. There must be a way to generalise this and typeset in a much simpler way which will then work for any matrix I feed into the code regardless of its dimensions.

Thanks

Comment: What about: `eq= Table[S[[i]] == Sum[x[[r, i]] E[[r]], {r, \[Lambda]}], {i, n}]`

Comment: @DanielHuber, and then just solve eq for x?

Comment: Yes, `eq` gives the equations for `x`

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)
```

You cannot use [`E`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/E.html) as a variable name since it is used for the exponential constant. Use [DoubleStruckCapitalE] instead.

```
$Assumptions = Element[i | λ | n, Integers] && 
  i > 0 && λ > 0 && n > 0 && 
  Element[\[DoubleStruckCapitalE] | S, Vectors[λ]] && 
  Element[x, Matrices[{λ, n}]];

Format[\[DoubleStruckCapitalE][r_]] := 
  Subscript[Style[\[DoubleStruckCapitalE], Italic], r];

Format[S[i_]] := Subscript[S, i];

Format[x[r_, i_]] := Subscript[x, r, i]

(eqn = S[i] == 
    Sum[HoldForm[x[r, i]*\[DoubleStruckCapitalE][r]], {r, 
      1, λ}]) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Or in [`StandardForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm.html)

```
eqn // ReleaseHold
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that E cannot be used as a variable name. I just used it here as a placeholder, but I'll keep that in mind in the future. From your answer it is still unclear to me (or maybe I was unclear in my original question) how to solve for x. So far what I've tried either throws out errors or gives me a solution of 'x', which is most unhelpful.